# How does DYNAMIC Row format handle NULL storage MYSQL 5.7?

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-5.7, row, data-pages

As a newbie to Mysql I just can't understand how NULL values are stored in each row formats.

As per [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-physical-record.html#innodb-redundant-row-format-characteristics)(last bullet-in), NULLs for fixed length columns (BIGINTs) also take their data space reserved. Meanwhile, NULLs for variable length columns are handled differently. The behaviour is defined under REDUNDANT row format description. I doubt what will be the behaviour with DYNAMIC / COMPRESSED row formats?

Note: I have tried to create 997 bigints in a table and have inserted value for one column. I had around 1957 rows but only had 26 pages, which means NULLs doesn't occupy space for fixed length. Am I understanding it in correct way? Please anyone help! 
Specifications: 5.7.23 | Innodb | Dynamic Row | 16kb page size

Comment: I verified page count with py_innodb_page_info.py script

Comment: It is rarely wise to have more than 100 columns of any type in a table.  Please explain the table further; we may have other advice that looks beyond just the `NULL` question you have posed.

Answer (score 0):

The second bullet point 'The variable-length part of the record header contains a bit vector for indicating NULL columns'.

So when a row has a field that is NULL, the bit in the bit vector of the header is set.

AFAIK this is the same for DYNAMIC/COMPRESSED that really only changed the handling of variable length fields.

Comment: So, DYNAMIC/COMPRESSED/COMPACT row formats doesn't reserve data-space for null values. But, REDUNDANT do. Am I correct?

Comment: [For a detailed analysis rather than guessing, look at the code](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/b93c1661d689c8b7decc7563ba15f6ed140a4eb6/storage/innobase/row/row0sel.cc#L2877)